# UDDI - find service which name matches exactly name specified in request

Tags: c#, .net, uddi

I'm asking UDDI to find a service with a name specified in request. The code looks like this:

```
UddiConnection uddiConnection = new UddiConnection(uddiAddress);
FindService findService = new FindService();
findService.Names.Add(uddiServiceName);                
ServiceList foundServices = findService.Send(uddiConnection);
```

However, when I ask for SomeService and UDDI has two services SomeService and SomeServiceSecond I get both in found services.

How can I ask for service that name exactly matches the name specified? I know I can check the result in my class and limit found services collection but I would like to specify my needs in UDDI inquire.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, though I don't know if the syntax is correct, but You can try using this line before Send():

```
findService.FindQualifiers = FindQualifier.ExactNameMatch;
```

Comment: The exact code is findService.FindQualifiers.Add(FindQualifier.ExactNameMatch); - thanks!